# Azure portal, how to give logic app permissions to a Ad-secured App Service

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an App Service thats Ad-secured so that you have to be a signed in user(same tenant) and member of a group to have access to the app.

I now need to create a logic app that ping an endpoint on my app.

I have tried both system and user assigned identity on the logic app, assigned a managed identity and added the identity to the group with permission to the app as well as give the identity an assigned role as an owner to the app.

I've also tried give the logic app an assigned role as owner.

I get 401 when trying to call the endpoint from my logic app.

When I google it I only get answer of how to secure my logic app.

Any suggestions of hot to set this up correctly?

Thanks

After doing as suggested I still get an error

[image]

[image]

I've probably missing some setting?
But shouldn't this be able to get done by using managed identitys in some way?

Answer (score 0):

When you request the endpoint in logic app, you can use "Authentication" in "HTTP" action.

[image]

Since your app is secured by AD, so you should have a registered app as client app in AD and another app as backend app in AD. The info you need to provide is shown as below screenshot. "Audience" is `api://{the client id of your backend app in AD}/.default`.

[image]

Comment: I've updated my question after trying your suggestion.

Comment: @CarlDecks It seems the Authentication in "HTTP" of logic app uses v1 get token endpoint. Could you please have a try with using `api://xxxxx` without `/.default` in "Audience". Please note `xxxx` is the client id of registered app(as backend app) but not client if of registered app(as client app).